# Question about using string arrays as function parameters

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I am a novice, I encountered a little problem today, I hope to get someone's answer, thank you very much.
Code show as below。

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void sub(char b[]){
    b[] = "world";    //I alse try b*/b,but it is not ok
}
int main(void){
    char a[10] = "hello";
    sub(a);
    cout<<a<<endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

error: expected primary-expression before ']' token
b[] = "world";
^
[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veh62.png)

I want the final output will be "world".  The function sub() can run correctly.  What should I do?

Comment: HaHaHaHa,you are right, i'm so careless.Next time I will pay attention.

Comment: Better to post the error message as text than only a picture.

Comment: Use `strcpy` to write into an existing `char` array (although you'd need more safety checks in a real program)

Comment: One doesn't simply assign to a char array. You have to use `std::strcpy` and friends. Plus, if this is really C++, then use `std::string`s instead of `char[]`.

Comment: `b[] = "world"; //I alse try b*/b,but it is not ok` -- You can't learn C++ properly by randomly trying things.  C++ is one of the most difficult languages to learn, and it is best to learn it by utilizing peer-reviewed C++ books.

Comment: OK, it's my first to use this web for asking question. i will add error message as text now.

Comment: What you should probably do is switch to a different textbook that actually teaches C++, and all of its classes, like `std::string`. Apparently, the textbook you're using is actually teaching C, not C++, since the fix here is to use a C library function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
strcpy(b, "world"); // need <string.h>
```

But I would use std::string (instead of c-string) directly.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using std::cout;
using std::string;

void sub(string &b){
    b = "world";
}

int main(){
    string a = "hello";
    sub(a);
    cout << a << endl; // output

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much.Other question:If i don't want to use strcpy and string just using array as a function parameter.what should i do？

Comment: @Hideonbush As far as I know, you just cannot assign a string literal to a c-string variable unless it's a declaration. However, you can assign characters one by one, like b[0] = 'w'; b[1] = 'o'; and so on.

Comment: Ok,Thanks for the prompt reply.Next time,I will not assign a string literal to a c-string variable unless it's a declaration.

Answer (score 0):

as other people told you it's not c++ style but c style, I will try to explain why it does not compile.
when you write `b[i]` you tell the compiler: "please go to memory location `b + sizeof(b type) * i`", so when you write `b[]`, the compiler can't understand what you want.

Comment: Thanks, good explanation. So `b[i]`  can only be assigned to a char type not string.